# Regular expression to match wildcard in a subdomain and one additional domain

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm writing a regex for a chrome extension in javascript and I want to target all the stackexchange subdomains and one outlier which is stackoverflow.com which doesnt have the same domain pattern.

https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/

https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/

https://stackoverflow.com/

So far I have:

```
/^https:\/\/(www\.)?stackoverflow.com/
```

This works to match stackoverflow, but when I try to add in the OR operator it doesn't work:

```
/^https:\/\/(*\.)?(stackoverflow.com|stackexchange.com)/
```

Comment: You're just missing a `.` before the `*` here: `^https:\/\/(.*\.)?(stackoverflow.com|stackexchange.com)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write the alternation like this for example

```
^https:\/\/(www\.)?(?:(?:bitcoin|ethereum)\.stackexchange|stackoverflow)\.com\/
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2WO8TW/1)